# Way to insert elements into list at variable depth?

Tags: python, list, recursion

How do I insert an element into a program-specified level of a list? My solution isn't very Pythonic:

```
def listInsertDepth(l,e,i,lvl): # Insert element e into list l at depth lvl using list of indices i
    if lvl < 0: # That is, if your depth level is invalid
        return l
    else:
        assert len(i) == lvl+1 # One index for every level, plus for the actual insertion
        s = l # A copy for tampering with
        for index in range(lvl):
            s = s[i[index]]
        s.insert(i[-1],e)
        return listInsertDepth(l,s,i[:-1],lvl-1)
```

Comment: Isn't the level given from the list of indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a series of indices, you can simply loop over them all except for the last one to traverse your nested structure to the parent list to insert into:

```
listInsertAtDepth(lst, value, indices):
    parent = lst
    for index in indices[:-1]:
        parent = parent[index]
    parent.insert(indices[-1], value)
```

You can add a `try`, `except` combo to detect that you got your index wrong:

```
listInsertAtDepth(lst, value, indices):
    parent = lst
    try:
        for index in indices[:-1]:
            parent = parent[index]
        parent.insert(indices[-1], value)
     except IndexError:
        return None
```

but personally, I'd rather get an exception than having it swallowed and discarded like that.

Note that you should not return `lst` from your function, as it is altered in-place. Python stdlib methods like `.append()` and `.extend()`, that modify a list in-place don't return anything either.